# Is there a way to find the counts of unique binary arrays in a list of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

If I had a numpy array in the form of

```
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 1.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.], 
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

is there a way to determine the frequency of these binary arrays?

Using the example listed above, the frequencies would be something like [1.0.0.0.0] - 4, [0.1.1.1.1] - 2. I've tried using np.unique, but that returns the counts of just unique numbers which isn't super helpful in this case.

Comment: What are the typical dimensions of your array?

Comment: It can range, but typically 2000 rows x 10 columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(map(tuple, arr))
```

`map(tuple, arr)` converts each row of the array to a tuple which is hashable and thus can be stored in a mapping like Counter.

Answer (score 3):

Using only `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1,]])

c = np.unique(b, axis=0, return_counts=True)
print(c)
```

```
>>> (array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([2, 4], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people have given you answers, but I just wanted to point out that if you turn the inside into something like a tuple as others suggested, np.unique does return counts as the 4th return argument

Answer (score 1):

If your array has no more than 64 columns, then you can convert the rows to numbers and then count with `np.unique`:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
                 [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
                 [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
# Convert each row into an integer
b = 1 << np.arange(data.shape[1], dtype=np.uint64)
nums = (b * data.astype(np.uint64)).sum(1)
# Count occurrences
vals, counts = np.unique(nums, return_counts=True)
# Make result
result = {tuple(((v & b) != 0).astype(np.uint8)): c for v, c in zip(vals, counts)}
print(result)
# {(1, 0, 0, 0, 0): 4, (0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
arrays = [[0. 1. 1. 1. 1.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.], 
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
print(len(set([tuple(i) for i in arrays])))
```

This removes duplicates and then measures the length of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have experience with text mining.  To expand your horizons, how about thinking of each row in the matrix as a string, i.e., a word.

When working with words, you can use a hashtable (dictionary) to count the numbers of times any word has been used in a list.  Dictionaries store what are called `Key-Value` pairs.  The first time a word is seen, it becomes a unique `Key`.  Thereafter, if you feed a dictionary a word that's already been seen, it will be detected as already being set to a `Key`, and if so, you simply pad the `Value` for that `Key` by one.

If you want to generate unique combinations of binary numbers (0,1), look at the "revolving door algorithm" by Donald Knuth.